# How to test spring batch job within @Transactional SpringBootTest test case?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-batch, spock, lazy-initialization

I just can't seem to win today...

1. Is there a way to read from a `OneToMany` relationship in a Spock SpringBootTest integration test, without annotating the test as `@Transactional` or adding the unrealistic `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true`?
2. OR, is there a way to launch a Spring-Batch Job from within a `@Transactional` test case?

Let me elaborate...

I'm trying to get a simple Spring Boot Integration test working for my Spring Batch reporting process, which reads from tangled web of DB2 tables and generates a series of change messages for interested systems. I'm using the Groovy Spock testing framework and an H2 in-memory database filled with a representative slice of my DB2 tables' data.

At the beginning of the test, I'm attempting to use every entity from a given Table to generate entries in a change-tracking table that drives my messaging.

```
setup:
List allExistingTestPeople = peopleRepository.findAll()
Collections.shuffle(allExistingTestPeople)
allExistingTestPeople?.each { Person person ->
    Nickname nicknames = person.nicknames
    nicknames?.each { Nickname nickname ->
        changeTrackingRepository.save(new Change(personId: person.id, nicknameId: nickname.id, status: NEW))
    }
}
```

Given these as my DB2 domain classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PERSON")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "P_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "P_NME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Nickname.class, mappedBy = "person")
    private List<Nickname> nicknames;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "T_NICKNAME")
public class Nickname{

    @EmbeddedId
    private PersonNicknamePK id;

    @Column(name = "N_NME")
    private String nickname;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, targetEntity = Person.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "P_ID", referencedColumnName="P_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Person person;
}

@Embeddable
public class PersonNicknamePK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="P_ID")
    private int personId;

    @Column(name="N_ID")
    private short nicknameId;
}
```

But I'm getting this LazyInitializationException, even though I'm reading from that `OneToMany` relationship within the context of a test case...

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.my.package.db2.model.Person.nicknames, could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:602)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:217)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:161)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:350)
```

I came across the advice online to annotate my test case with the `@Transactional` annotation, which definitely got me a little further, allowing me to read from this `OneToMany` relationship. However, when  I then attempt to launch the Spring Batch Job I'd like to test from my `when` clause:

```
@Transactional
def "Happy path test to validate I can generate a report of changes"() {
    setup:
    //... See above

    when:
    service.launchBatchJob()

    then:
    //... Messages are generated
}
```

I'm getting the exception that a Spring Batch Job can't be launched from the context of a transaction! Even though I'm using an in-memory Job manager via `ResourcelessTransactionManager` and `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean`, since this is just a short lived scheduled script I'm writing...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing transaction detected in JobRepository. Please fix this and try again (e.g. remove @Transactional annotations from client).
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:177)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
    at com.my.package.service.MyService.launchBatchJob(MyService.java:30)
```

The only thing that seems to work so far is if I scrap the `@Transactional` annotation and instead add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true` to my `application-test.properties` file. BUT, this doesn't seem like a very good idea, because it's not realistic - if I add this, then even if there's a bug in my code due to a lazy-initialization-exception, I'd never see it in the tests.

Sorry for the novel, hoping someone can point me in the right direction :(

---

EDIT:

Also here's my In-memory Spring-Batch configuration, in which I've tried turning off the transaction validation. Unfortunately, while this gets me a little further, the Spring Batch partioner's autowired EntityManager is suddenly failing to run queries in the H2 database.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class InMemoryBatchManagementConfig {

    @Bean
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager resourceslessTransactionManager() {
        ResourcelessTransactionManager resourcelessTransactionManager = new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
        resourcelessTransactionManager.setNestedTransactionAllowed(true);
        resourcelessTransactionManager.setValidateExistingTransaction(false);
        return resourcelessTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactory(ResourcelessTransactionManager txManager)
            throws Exception {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(txManager);
        factory.setValidateTransactionState(false);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory) throws Exception {
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        launcher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return launcher;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobExplorer jobExplorer(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory) {
        return new SimpleJobExplorer(factory.getJobInstanceDao(), factory.getJobExecutionDao(),
                factory.getStepExecutionDao(), factory.getExecutionContextDao());
    }

    @Bean
    public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactory,
                                           ResourcelessTransactionManager resourceslessTransactionManager,
                                           SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher,
                                           JobExplorer jobExplorer) {
        return new BatchConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public JobRepository getJobRepository() throws Exception {
                return mapJobRepositoryFactory.getObject();
            }

            @Override
            public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws Exception {
                return resourceslessTransactionManager;
            }

            @Override
            public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() throws Exception {
                return jobLauncher;
            }

            @Override
            public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() throws Exception {
                return jobExplorer;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a comment by someone who does not know squat about Spring Batch, only about testing: The moment I saw that you made the test method transactional, I smelled something bad. Whatever the best way to implement your test may be, I think this is not it. If you cannot test your code in a cleaner way, probably you have a design problem. Sorry to be so unspecific, I hope my advice to think about this test from a different angle somehow helps you find a better solution.

Comment: @SnoopDougg Do I understand correctly that you want "setup" to be in a transaction (so you can read of datasource without LIE) but the rest should be without it?

Comment: @Josef yah definitely! If that's possible in Spock, to put the setup clause in it's own little transaction, that would be awesome

Comment: And @kriegaex I believe that SpringBootTest integration tests are often wrapped within a transaction, no? So that any changes to the DB can be rolled back at the end of the test, if you can't happen to find an in-memory equivalent to mock you database.

Comment: That is is done often does not mean it is the right thing to do. Often people copy & paste from each other. --- _"The fact that an opinion has been widely held is no evidence whatever that it is not utterly absurd; indeed in view of the silliness of the majority of mankind, a widely spread belief is more likely to be foolish than sensible." Bertrand Russell_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do transactions programmatically using [`TransactionTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) to run only the "setup" inside a transaction (instead of having everything in `@Transactional`). Unfortunately this way the transaction will be committed and you will need to do some manual cleanup.

It can be autowired as any other bean:

```java
    @Autowired
    private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;
```

...and it's used this way:

```java
        transactionTemplate.execute((transactionStatus) -> {
            // ...setup...
            return null; // alternatively you can return some data out of the callback
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This error happens because your code will be already executed in a transaction driven by Spring Batch. So running the job in the scope of a transaction is not correct. However, if you still want to disable the transaction validation done by the job repository, you can set the `validateTransactionState` to false, see [AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean#setValidateTransactionState](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.html#setValidateTransactionState-boolean-).

That said, running the job in a transaction is not the way to fix `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`. The property `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true` is there for a reason, and if it works for you, I believe it is a better approach than running the entire job in a transaction (and btw, if I had to use a transaction for that, I would narrow its scope to the minimum (for example the step) and not the entire job).

Comment: Thank you! This got me a little further, I tried using `setValidateTransactionState(false)`, and now I'm not seeing that "Cant run job within transaction" error anymore. But for some reason my EntityManagerFactory that I've autowired into my Partioner can no longer run queries in the DB. I keep getting back a count of 0. Maybe it's because the earlier part of my test setup hasn't actually been commited... I'll keep tinkering to try and see what's going on